# remove square brackets and it content from string in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to remove characters between two brackets and brackets. For example

```
Let it [Am]be, let it [C/G]be, let it [F]be, let it [C]be
[C]Whisper words of [G]wisdom, let it [F]be [C/E] [Dm] [C]
```

I want above string to

```
Let it be, let it be, let it be, let it be
Whisper words of wisdom, let it be
```

I use this regx but it is only take out brackets.

```
var reg = /[\[\]']+/g
var x = song.replace(reg,"")
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the *outer* `[]` so you're matching those literally, and allow anything except a `]` inside. So:

```
var reg = /\[[^\]]*\]/g;
```

Here's a breakdown (also on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/2oTQ6T/1)):

- `\[` matches `[` literally
- `[^\]]` matches any character that isn't a `]`
- `*` says "zero or more" of those (so it replaces `[]`; if you don't want that, change this to `+` for "one or more")
- `\]` matches `]` literally (I probably don't need to escape it there, but I tend to anyway)

Live Example:

```js
const song = `Let it [Am]be, let it [C/G]be, let it [F]be, let it [C]be
[C]Whisper words of [G]wisdom, let it [F]be [C/E] [Dm] [C]`;

var reg = /\[[^\]]*\]/g;
var x = song.replace(reg,"");
console.log(x);
```

---

Side note: In modern JavaScript, we don't use `var`. Use `let` or `const` instead.